# python script to get all .mp3 files in mulitiple subfolders and move to one folder on a pc?

Tags: python

Does anyone have a smooth python script to gather and move files with a certain extension from many subfolders to one folder on a PC?

Comment: Please try yourself first! I am familiar with python and you can do that in 10 lines of code. I believe in you! :)

Comment: Do you really need it in python? A simple command line should be enough for this.

Comment: Use os.walk() and os.rename() together with tuple with filendings. One tip I always give is to not use os.rename() but just print(originpath, endpath) to verify things look like you expect them too. When that works go ahead and change print to os rename. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using glob:

First find all the files that end with `.mp3`:

```
import os
filepath = []
for path, _, files in os.walk('./'):
    #You might want to exclude some directories or limit search files found to directories:
    #exclude paths that have 'Program Files' folder and only include all paths that have 'Downloads',
    #ie derp/Downloads/a/ or Downloads/durp/ included, anything with 'Program Files' excluded
    if ('Program Files' not in path) and ('Downloads' in path):
        #in case of windows system replace \ with /
        filepath.extend([os.path.join(path, file).replace('\\', '/') for file in files
                         if str(file).endswith('.mp3')])
```

Now that you have the list of files with full filepath move them to new place:

```
for file in filepath:
    os.rename(filepath, 'new/folder' + os.path.split(filpath)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from dkfileutils.path import Path
[mp3.move('/destination/dir') for mp3 in Path('/source/dir').glob('**/*.mp3')]
```

(full disclosure: I'm the author of dkfileutils)

Answer (score -1):

```
os.chdir("D:\DOWNLOAD")                  # Change file direction first
for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):      # search for the *.mp3 extension 
    time.sleep(1)
    shutil.move("path/to/current/file", "path/to/new/destination/for/file")
```

something like this, you have to add walk through os function to get all sub direction,

Comment: you have to use glob